# Running bat file using Windows scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I wanted to run a .bat file in Windows task scheduler, so I opened it, added a new task, browsed to the bat file, and... nothing happened.

So I changed the timing to see if it'll run, and it didn't. Next I right-clicked on the task and chose "run", it didn't run. The file itself is only one line, basicly backups a folder to a another location. It runs fine when not in the scheduler.

When I asked on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526861/running-bat-file-using-windows-schedualer) they first said to come here and the other guy said to write:

```
cmd.exe /C completepathtobatchfile argstobatchfileifany
```

So I wrote:

```
cmd.exe /C k:\backup.bat
```

and it didn't work. What do I have to change to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to just use the [`at` command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565).

For example to run the batch file located at: `C:\script.bat` at 4 AM every Tuesday you would do the following in a command-prompt:

```
at 4:00 /every:T "C:\script.bat"
```

Comment: T is for Tuesday

Comment: Yes, and Th is for Thursday.

Comment: what about doing that every day? or two days for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. I believe that in XP a batch file must use full pathnames, e.g. "C:\utility\file.exe" instead of just "filename.exe".  The batch file run from the scheduler does not necessarily have a PATH or a current directory.  That's for executables and targets both.
2. Also, in XP I believe that filenames are limited to the old DOS-style 8+3 system.  Try reducing filename (and directory name) lengths to the short version.

Comment: Even in XP, any batch file in a path on your PATH should be found.

Comment: I was referring to using full paths INSIDE the batch file, not necessarily the path TO the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at several related answers on SuperUser.com, and not wanting to use a workaround, I finally found the answer on StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13173752/261405

The important piece from there:
At the 'Action' settings - "Start in (Optional)" option.

Without this, it would never work for me