# using "at" command in command line to create repeatable tasks

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I got an answer about [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/51808/running-bat-file-using-windows-scheduler/51810#51810), about 2 years ago,  
but now I want to use the same command to create a task that will run every half an hour. How can that be done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: forgot to say: i use windows 7

Comment: Based on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772590.aspx) and [Sample](http://serverfault.com/questions/93453/does-anyone-have-a-windows-at-every-example-to-explain-how-to-setup-a-batch), it looks like that may not be supported by AT.  AT allows specifying days, not minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `schtasks` instead:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn "Task runs Every 30 Minuts" /tr c:\PATH\TO\TASK.exe
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_minutes

Comment: ok i'll check it

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: To create the task to run as the system account—something you can't do via the Scheduled Tasks GUI, but which happens automatically when you use the `at` command—use `schtasks … /ru System …`.