# How to run a bat or vbs file in task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, task-scheduler

I have a .bat file that is one line long and calls up a vb script that specifically opens an excel file and runs some macros:

```
cscript priordays.vbs "C:\PATHANME\FILENAME.xlsm"
```

When I run it by double clicking, it runs fine and successfully.

When I run in task scheduler, it says it ran successfully (code 0x0), but the script does not execute.  I've got it set to run with highest permissions, regardless of whether or not the user is logged in, wake machine, etc.  Still nothing.

For those asking what's in the vb script, it's:

```
Dim arts, objExcel

Set args = WScript.ARguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.visible = True

objExcel.Run "Macro1"
objExcel.Run "Macro2"
objExcel.Run "Macro3"

objWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Quit
```

I found that code elsewhere on this site, along with the instructions on using the .bat file.  If there's a way to run it all from the script, and try to launch the script from task scheduler, I'm fine to do that as well.

Comment: The problem is that office com automation doesn't work in a scheduled task out of the box. It's quite tricky to get this to actually work as it involves changing permissions in the 32bit dcom management console (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dcomcnfg.exe`).  I don't have a proper documentation at hand atm, but that should point you into the right direction.

Comment: I can find the file, but I'm not sure what to do with it. I am well out of my depth, I believe.

Comment: You can try making a startup macro for office and then just run cscript Excel.exe and then the startup macro will run and close excel.

Comment: Here's a MS link that explains how to do it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-or-microsoft-word-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in/

Comment: @megamorf, I went in and gave all permissions, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @RamonRobben, Do you mean a macro that runs when Excel starts up? I need something that automatically triggers every day at the same time.

Comment: @mbald23 1. make a script that runs everyday to start Excel 2. Make a Macro that starts when excel starts. this way you start excel everyday and excel will start the macro.

Comment: @RamonRobben, I could put a macro on this workbook that would run when it opens.  How would I create the script that runs every day that starts Excel in the right workbook?

Comment: @mbald23 Take a look at this question. http://superuser.com/questions/51808/running-bat-file-using-windows-scheduler?rq=1

Comment: You're saying using the at command, to set up in command line that it will run every day?

Comment: @mbald23 Yes exactly. This is the command you can use e.x at 20:30 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su "Excel.exe" now everyday its will launch excel at 8:30 PM and excel will ofcourse launch the startup macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Megamorf said in his comment its really tricky to do. So you would be better off using a startup macro and a sheduled start to achieve your goal.

How it works? You make a startup macro for excel which will start everytime that excel starts.

If you combine this with the scheduled start using the [at](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks) command from the following question: [Running bat file using Windows scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/51808/running-bat-file-using-windows-scheduler?rq=1)

For you the AT command would be e.x

```
at 20:30 /every:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su "excel.exe"
```

This will start excel every day at 8:30 PM. Excel will run the startup macro.

**How to Cancel a Scheduled Task**

1. Click Start, point to Programs, point to Accessories, and then click
   Command Prompt.
2. At the command prompt, type the following line, and then press ENTER
   to display a list of currently running services:

   net start
3. If Task Scheduler is not displayed in the list, type the following
   line, and then press ENTER:

   net start "task scheduler"
4. At the command prompt, type the following line (use the parameters
   that are appropriate to your situation), and then press ENTER:

   at \computername id /delete | /delete/yes

\\computername is a computer that is in a network. You do not have to fill that in.

Comment: Giving this a shot momentarily.  If I want to stop this at some point, what would I used as my stop script?

Comment: @mbald23 when you visit the link from at command and scroll down a but you will see instructions on how to cancle the command. I'll add it to my answer aswell.

Comment: Ran into an issue.  Not sure if there's a way to upload screenshots, but command rejected it as invalid.

Comment: @mbald23 you can upload screenshots to a site from imgur or something and post the link.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/He0Lb

Comment: @mbald23 you would have to play with the command a bit. IT could be that you are making a mistake try some different times maybe different dates and then check if that works like at 4:00 /every:T "excel.exe" or maybe make a script and run that instead of excel.exe not sure why it wouldnt work but you could try some things.

Comment: I think I got it.  We'll see if it runs properly tomorrow morning.  Thanks so much for all the help!